# LeetCode 24 - Swap Nodes in Pairs (Explanation and Visualization of the code)

Tags: c, recursion, data-structures, linked-list, swap

```
/** 
 * Definition for singly-linked list. 
 * struct ListNode { 
 *     int val; 
 *     struct ListNode *next; 
 * }; 
 */ 

struct ListNode* swapPairs(struct ListNode* head){ 

    if(!head || !head -> next) 
        return head; 

    struct ListNode *newHead = head -> next; 
    head -> next = swapPairs(newHead -> next); 
    newHead -> next = head; 
    return newHead; 

}
```

Given that a linked list, 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5, I know that when this linked list enter the function signature, "struct ListNode* swapPairs(struct ListNode* head)", "*newHead" is the node containing value 2, which is the second node of the linked list.

head is the pointer to the first node containing value 1.
newHead -> next is the pointer to the node containing value 3 (3rd node).

But why "head -> next = swapPairs(newHead -> next)" returns the node containing value 3, which is the third node of the linked list? I don't get why "swapPairs(newHead -> next)" can make "head -> next" point to the third node of the linked list.

I expected that "swapPairs(newHead -> next)" will return a linked list pointer, with a linked list 4 -> 3 -> 5" to "head -> next".

I thought it will return the node containing value 4 and all the pair nodes are swapped after the second node of the linked list.

Comment: Please format your question properly. Indent code blocks by 4 characters.

Comment: The best explanation comes from you drawing out the operations on a piece of paper and explaining it to your rubber duck: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/281271/17592432

Comment: *But why "head -> next = swapPairs(newHead -> next)" returns the node containing value 3* How do you know? Please post what you directly observe, not what you deduce. A [mcve] would be the best way to convey this information.

Answer (score -1):

The code will work as expected.

Taking your case of the singly linked list 1->2->3->4->5 as example, the final result of the processing in the function `swapPairs()` will make the list as 2->1->4->3->5.

Inside the function `swapPairs()` , for each pair of nodes, consider that `head` is the pointer to the old head node (i.e the first node in the pair) and `newHead` is to become the pointer to the new head node (i.e the second node in the pair) of the to-be-swapped pair.

`swapPairs()` is called for every adjacent pair of nodes in the entire list and this function returns the first node of the swapped pair which needs to be assigned as the `next` pointer to the old head node of the previous pair which is yet to be swapped.

A walk through:

For the very first call of the function `swapPairs()`, `head` will be pointing to 1 and `newHead` pointing to 2.

On the second call (recursive) to `swapPairs()`, `head` will be pointing to 3 and `newHead` pointing to 4.

On the third call (recursive), `head` will be pointing to 5 and `head->next` is NULL. `head` being NULL or `head->next` being NULL is the base case which causes the recursion to stop as per this code:

```
if(!head || !head -> next) 
        return head;
```

When this third call returns the old head (5) to it's caller, in the caller `head->next` of the old head node of the to-be-swapped pair ( 3 and 4) in the caller will be now set to 5.This causes the node 3 to now point to 5:

```
head -> next = swapPairs(newHead -> next);
```

`newHead` which is pointing to 4 will be set to point to the old head node (3) as per the code:

```
newHead -> next = head; 
    return newHead;
```

The swap of nodes 3 and 4 is complete. And 4 (as pointed to by `newHead`) will be returned back to the previous `swapPairs()` call.

Now when we are back to the very first call of `swapPairs()`: the old head (pointing to 1) will be set to point to 4 which was returned as the first node of the pair (3,4) from the first recursive invocation of `swapPairs()` while `newHead`is pointing to 2. All that remains is to make `newHead->next` point to 1 now, thus swapping of 1 and 2 is now completed , then return the pointer `newHead` (pointing to to 2) back to `main()` or any other caller that called `swapPairs()` on the entire linked list.